# Escape comma in ansible win_lineinfile module

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a PowerShell script file: `C:\Workdir\createLog.ps1`

I want to comment out this line `Remove-Item -Force ($Path + '*' + $Suffix);` in the script

I use ansible to do it automatically, using `win_lineinfile` module. The code is like this:

```
- name: Comment out content
    win_lineinfile:
      path: "C:\\Workdir\\createLog.ps1"
      regexp: '^(\s+)Remove-Item -Force \(\$Path \+ \'\*\' \+ \$Suffix\);'
      line: '$1# Remove-Item -Force ($Path + '*' + $Suffix);'
      backrefs: yes
```

But it returns an error, because `'*'` cannot pass as string at regexp

Comment: Where is the comma in your pattern that you are trying to match? There is none.

Comment: My original string in powershell script file is: Remove-Item -Force ($Path + '*' + $Suffix);

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to find lines with any amount of whitespace before a line with the `Remove-Item -Force ($Path + '*' + $Suffix);` contents and add a `#` + space after the leading whitespace.

You can use

```
regexp: '^(\s*)(Remove-Item -Force \(\$Path \+ \'\*\' \+ \$Suffix\);)'
line: '\1#\2'
backrefs: yes
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqNZ6q/1). `\1#\2` in the `backrefs` parameter specify that the replacement should be Group 1 value + `#` + Group 2 value.

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string/line here
- `(\s*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): zero or more whitespaces
- `(Remove-Item -Force \(\$Path \+ \'\*\' \+ \$Suffix\);)` - Group 2 (`\2`): `Remove-Item -Force ($Path + '*' + $Suffix);` string.

You might want to replace the literal spaces with `\s+` (one or more) or `\s*` (zero or more whitespace) to match any kind of whitespace.

Comment: It seem still get error.

As long as there are commas inside commas, thay cannot pass as string.

I tried with this way to avoid commas inside commas, and it can work.

`- name: Comment out content
  win_lineinfile:
    path: "C:\\Workdir\\createLog.ps1"
    regexp: '^(\s+)Remove-Item -Force \(\$LogPath \+ (.*) \+ \$Suffix\);'
    line: '$1# Remove-Item -Force ($Path + $2 + $Suffix);'
    backrefs: yes
  with_items: "{{ txt_file }}"
  register: replace`

Thank you very much, or do you have any better idea?